# Creating a Clickable Link Using MySql Fetch Array and Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I am trying to use specific numeric results from a mysql_fetch_array within a while loop to execute a Javascript function (Ajax).  A basic snippet of my php code is as follows:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
$link = $data['id']; //example results will be 12345
echo '<span id="val" onclick="goto()">'.$link.'</span>'; //lists 12345, and makes each clickable
}
```

Part of my Javascript code is as follows:

```
function goto(str)
{
   Ajax...
   var idval = document.getElementById('val').innerHTML; //grabs 1,2,3,4, or 5 based on which number was clicked
   Ajax...
}
```

What I am trying to do here is query multiple records from MySql, list the results using a while loop, make each result clickable, and pass the inner html to a variable for Ajax.

My problem is that when I click any of the results from the while loop list, I pass only the first result of the mysql fetch array.  For example, the while loop will list 12345.  when I try clicking 3, I get 1 as the inner html; when I try clicking 5, I get 1 as the inner html; and so on...  It always gets the first result, which is 1.

I tried imploding and exploding the mysql fetch array, however the inner html always ends up being the first row of the array results.  I need to break up the array somehow, so that each row is independent, not just visually, but programmatically so I can get it using getElementById.innerHTML.

I really appreciate anyones help.  Your suggestions and hopefully an answer will really help make my php projects much more useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change your php script to look like this:

```
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    $link = $data['id']; //example results will be 12345
    echo '<span id="val'.$link.'" onclick="goto('.$link.')">'.$link.'</span>';
}
```

Then, use the following javascript code:

```
function goto(link)
{
    Ajax...
    var idval = document.getElementById('val'+link).innerHTML; 
    Ajax...
}
```

But I am not sure about what `str` means in your javascript code and why function `goto` takes 1 arguments (`str`) while is called with no arguments (`onclick="goto()"`).

Comment: Hi develroot - You rock! Your suggestion worked.  Upon your changes, I added: function goto(link, str), and now everything works well.  The (str) refers to ajax: url = url+"?q"+str;  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you use id="val" in your span elements. So you could only get the first element. So you end up getting first span's inner html all the time.

The simplest solution is to pass id value as an argument to your goto function call.

Update: you may modifier your function as below:

```
function goto(link)
{
    Ajax...
    var idval = link;
    Ajax...
}
```

Comment: Hi domx - thanks for your suggestion.  Are you saying to do something like: onclick=goto('.$link.')?  I tried this, but I do not know how to get the value from my javascript function.  I only know getElementBy attributes.